# Data.Vector.modify with nested vectors

Tags: haskell, haskell-vector

I have a vector nested inside another. [I want to use `modify`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.1/docs/Data-Vector.html#v:modify) to update this matrix in place. So I use it for the inner vector, but do I also need to use it for the outer?

Comment: If you want to modify a matrix, why don't you use a matrix instead of a vector? Here is a similar way to manipulate an array of arbitrary dimension as you would do with `modify` on vector: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/massiv-0.4.0.0/docs/Data-Massiv-Array-Mutable.html#v:withMArrayST

Comment: Yep. First to it say which row to modify, then you say how to modify that row (i.e. modify the element).

Comment: Unless you expect a ragged array, vector of vectors approach should be avoided, since it has serious drawbacks. First of all performance penalty: the outer vector has to be boxed (which means an extra pointer indirection), secondly safety: you can't guarantee the length of your rows, and last but not least, operating on it becomes very cumbersome ;)

Comment: I wish the hackage page for Vector would have given this advice! It would have saved me days of headache.

Comment: You could submit a pull request to the vector package to work it into the summary so it appears on hackage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion from the comments still stands, if you do not need to operate on a ragged array then the usual rectangular array implementation is better. Here is a short list of drawbacks of vector of vectors:

- performance penalty: the outer vector has to be boxed (which means an extra pointer indirection)
- safety: you can't guarantee the same length of all rows
- operating on ragged arrays is cumbersome

Nevertheless question still stands: how would you modify a vector of vectors in place. Below I'll provide an example function, which uses mutation to reverse rows of a ragged array and another function that reverses both rows and columns. Difference is that in the former we only mutate elements of each row, while in the latter we also mutate the outer boxed vector that corresponds to rows themselves:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
import Control.Monad as M
import Control.Monad.ST
import Prelude as P
import Data.Vector as V
import Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable as VGM
import Data.Vector.Mutable as VM
import Data.Vector.Primitive as VP
import Data.Vector.Primitive.Mutable as VPM

raggedModifyRows ::
     VP.Prim a
  => (forall s. V.Vector (VPM.MVector s a) -> ST s ())
  -> V.Vector (VP.Vector a)
  -> V.Vector (VP.Vector a)
raggedModifyRows action arr = runST $ do
  -- thaw will create a copy of each row, so they can be safely modified
  mvs <- V.mapM VP.thaw arr
  action mvs
  -- We are freezing mutated copies, so it is safe to use unsafeFreeze here too
  V.mapM VP.unsafeFreeze mvs

raggedModify ::
     VP.Prim a
  => (forall s. VM.MVector s (VPM.MVector s a) -> ST s ())
  -> V.Vector (VP.Vector a)
  -> V.Vector (VP.Vector a)
raggedModify action arr = runST $ do
  arr' <- V.mapM VP.thaw arr
  -- mapM already created a copy of a boxed vector, so we can use unsafeThaw
  mv <- V.unsafeThaw arr'
  action mv
  v <- V.unsafeFreeze mv
  V.mapM VP.unsafeFreeze v

generateMatrix ::
     Prim a => (Int, Int) -> ((Int, Int) -> a) -> V.Vector (VP.Vector a)
generateMatrix (m, n) f = V.generate m $ \ i -> VP.generate n $ \j -> f (i, j)

generateRagged ::
     Prim a => V.Vector Int -> ((Int, Int) -> a) -> V.Vector (VP.Vector a)
generateRagged v f = V.imap (\ i n -> VP.generate n $ \j -> f (i, j)) v

reverseST :: (VGM.MVector v a) => v s a -> ST s ()
reverseST mv =
  let n = VGM.length mv
   in M.forM_ [0 .. (n `div` 2) - 1] $ \j -> VGM.swap mv j (n - j - 1)

reverseRaggedRows :: Prim a => V.Vector (VP.Vector a) -> V.Vector (VP.Vector a)
reverseRaggedRows = raggedModifyRows $ \rows -> V.forM_ rows reverseST

reverseRagged :: Prim a => V.Vector (VP.Vector a) -> V.Vector (VP.Vector a)
reverseRagged =
  raggedModify $ \mrows -> do
    let reverse' i = VM.read mrows i >>= reverseST
    let m = VM.length mrows
    M.forM_ [0 .. (m `div` 2) - 1] $ \i -> do
      reverse' i
      VM.swap mrows i (m - i - 1)
      reverse' i
    M.when (odd m) $ reverse' (m `div` 2)
```

Which can be used as follows:

```hs
λ> m = generateMatrix (3, 4) $ \(i, j) -> i+j
λ> m
[[0,1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5]]
λ> reverseRaggedRows m
[[3,2,1,0],[4,3,2,1],[5,4,3,2]]
λ> reverseRagged m
[[5,4,3,2],[4,3,2,1],[3,2,1,0]]
λ> m = generateRagged (V.fromList [1,2,3]) $ \(i, j) -> i+j
λ> m
[[0],[1,2],[2,3,4]]
λ> reverseRaggedRows m
[[0],[2,1],[4,3,2]]
λ> reverseRagged m
[[4,3,2],[2,1],[0]]
```

Alternatively we could have used `Data.Vector.modify` to operate on the outer vector or map a destructive action that uses `modify` across all rows. There are all sorts of ways to go about it, depends on what you are trying to achieve, for example:

```hs
λ> m = generateRagged (V.fromList [1,2,3]) $ \(i, j) -> i+j
λ> V.map (VP.modify reverseST) m
[[0],[2,1],[4,3,2]]
λ> V.modify reverseST (V.map (VP.modify reverseST) m)
[[4,3,2],[2,1],[0]]
```

I did recommend using [`massiv`](https://github.com/lehins/massiv) for regular multidimensional arrays. Therefore here is also an example of how to achieve the same with [`withMArrayST`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/massiv-0.4.0.0/docs/Data-Massiv-Array-Mutable.html#v:withMArrayST):

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
import Control.Monad as M
import Data.Massiv.Array as A

reverseMatrix :: Mutable r Ix2 e => Array r Ix2 e -> Array r Ix2 e
reverseMatrix arr =
  withMArrayST arr $ \marr -> do
    let Sz2 m n = msize marr
        ix2@(m2 :. n2) = m `div` 2 :. n `div` 2
    A.forM_ (0 ..: ix2) $ \ix@(i :. j) -> do
      A.swapM_ marr ix (m - i - 1 :. n - j - 1)
      A.swapM_ marr (i :. n - j - 1) (m - i - 1 :. j)
    when (odd m) $ A.forM_ (0 ..: n2) $ \ j ->
      A.swapM_ marr (m2 :. j) (m2 :. n - j - 1)
    when (odd n) $ A.forM_ (0 ..: m2) $ \ i ->
      A.swapM_ marr (i :. n2) (m - i - 1 :. n2)
```

Which can be used as follows:

```hs
λ> a = makeArrayR P Seq (Sz2 3 4) $ \ (i :. j) -> i + j
λ> a
Array P Seq (Sz (3 :. 4))
  [ [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ]
  , [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
  , [ 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
  ]
λ> reverseMatrix a
Array P Seq (Sz (3 :. 4))
  [ [ 5, 4, 3, 2 ]
  , [ 4, 3, 2, 1 ]
  , [ 3, 2, 1, 0 ]
  ]
```

Comment: In `reverseMatrix`, what does the constraint `Mutable r Ix2 e` achieve? Does it refer to `Data.Massiv.Array.Mutable` ?

Comment: And how could I modify the matrix by modifying the element, say from `Int` to `(Int, String)`? For starters, I would think `r` in the type signature would need to be constrained to `U`.

Comment: > Does it refer to Data.Massiv.Array.Mutable ?
It refers to class https://www.stackage.org/haddock/nightly-2019-08-27/massiv-0.4.0.0/Data-Massiv-Array-Mutable.html#t:Mutable

But all functions in the above mentioned module will work on arrays that have an instance of that class

Comment: Yes using `U` for `r` is good, except that `String` (`[Char]`) doesn't have an `Unbox` instance, so converting elements to `(Int, String)` is not a good idea. Secondly, once you have a mutable array, you cannot change the type of its element. Which is obvious if you think about it, elements of different type are likely to occupy more memory, so you'd have to allocate new mutable array and fill it in.
All that being said, very often it is possible to avoid mutable interface and rewrite an algorithm in a pure fashion, give it a try.

Comment: To modify the element, I could convert the array to list, map, then convert back to array (of new element type) -- but is this overly expensive?

Comment: It will be ridiculously expensive, avoid using lists at all cost, unless you don't care about performance. There are many functions in `massiv`, including `map`, so checkout the examples and look through the readme and I am sure you'll find what you are looking for. There was also a workshop I did couple months ago, if you want to learn more about massiv: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=euEacUD6jQQ